# ubuntu 18.04 + kernel 5.1: installing nvidia GTX1050

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, kernel

I have a dell xps 15 9560 with a nvidia GTX 1050 and I have a problem trying to make work the nvidia drivers 430 (the recommended by ubuntu-drivers) on ubuntu 18.04 using gnome on Xorg under the kernel 5.1.x .

I have already tried executing `sudo apt purge nvidia-*`, rebooting and installing it both by `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430` or `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` and on rebooting the Settings > About panel keeps saying I'm using the intel HD 630 graphic card, also nvidia-smi states that there's no nvidia grpahic card running or no nvidia-driver installed.

I have these grub commands:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_rev_override=1 nouveau.modeset=0 nouveau.runpm=0 noresume intel_pstate=skylake_hwp"`

`grep -rnw /lib/modprobe.d/ -e "nvidia"` gives me the next results:

```
/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf:1:# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf:3:options nvidia-drm modeset=1
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:2:# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:3:blacklist nvidia
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:4:blacklist nvidia-drm
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:5:blacklist nvidia-modeset
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:6:alias nvidia off
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:7:alias nvidia-drm off
/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf:8:alias nvidia-modeset off
```

I had no problems using kernel 5.0 and using nvidia drivers 418, but on trying to return back to 5.0 it stopped working (I could boot, but ubuntu didn't detect any nvidia running).

I ran out of ideas (apart from reinstalling the whole OS) so I hope someone can help me diagnose what changed and make it work again...

Thanks!

Update 1:
As asked, here are the outputs:
`mokutil --sb-state`

```
SecureBoot disabled
```

`test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"`

```
efi
```

`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

```
x11
```

`dkms status`

```
nvidia, 418.56, 5.0.12-050012-generic, x86_64: installed
```

`sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`lsmod | grep nvidia` (returned empty)

`lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D|Display)"`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [1028:07be]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
```

Also, `prime-select query` returns `nvidia`.

Thanks!

Update 2: As counseled by  @Marmayogi, the `/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf` contains the following:

```
# Do not modify
# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
blacklist nvidia
blacklist nvidia-drm
blacklist nvidia-modeset
alias nvidia off
alias nvidia-drm off
alias nvidia-modeset off
```

Update 3: As asked, the results of the commands are:

`dkms status`

```
nvidia, 430.09, 5.0.0-050000-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 430.09, 5.1.3-050103-generic, x86_64: installed
```

`uname -r`

```
5.1.3-050103-generic
```

`ls -al /etc/boot`

```
ls: cannot access '/etc/boot': No such file or directory
```

`dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64         430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-418             418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-common-430             430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:amd64      430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:i386       430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:amd64       430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:i386        430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:amd64       430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:i386        430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64         430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386          430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:amd64           430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:i386            430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64         430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386          430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-430         430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-430                  430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-430                430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-430         430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-430         430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                     0.8.8.2                    all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                  418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-430                 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430    430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 quimere quimere 4096 ene 22 08:02 .
drwx------ 3 quimere quimere 4096 may 18 23:46 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 quimere quimere 4096 ene 22 08:02 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Comment: Why is ` Nvidia` blacklisted?

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"` 3. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` 4. `dkms status` 5. `sudo lshw -c video`   6. `lsmod | grep nvidia` and 7. `lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D|Display)"`

Comment: @Marmayogi Not sure, shouldn't be blacklisted in any file, specially considering I `prime-select query` returns `nvidia`. I have updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Nivida-418 is installed as indicated by `dkms` command output but driver is not loaded in kernel (refer `lspci` command output). Command `lshw` outputs `*-display UNCLAIMED ` and did not show the presence of Nvidia driver. Please look into `/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf` file and check whether Nvidia is blacklisted or not. Please report. Thanks.

Comment: @Marmayogi updated question with your comment. Also, executing `sudo prime-select intel`didn't change the file but executing once more `sudo prime-select nvidia` deleted that file and generated nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and nvidia-kms.conf

Seeing this change in files, I tried to restart but nvidia keeps without working.

Comment: `sudo dkms remove` the current Nvidia dkms driver on kernel 5.0.12, remove non-standard kernels 5.0.12 and 5.1, and go back to the standard kernel 5.0.0.-xx. Reinstall Nvidia 430 (make sure you don't have the beta version) or 418, and it should all work again.

Comment: I agree with @heynnema If new drivers and new kernel cause problem use old ones. I'd go a step further and get off 5 chain altogether and get on `4.14` LTS or `4.19` LTS kernels for 5 years of support. This way you aren't changing kernel chains every couple / few months. If you have brand new hardware supported only by brand new kernel that is a different story of course.

Comment: @heynnema I tried removing all dkms modules and purging nvidia and reinstalling it without removing the kernels, building the nvidia drivers in the 5.0 kernel (it built both for the 5.1.3 and 5.0.0), and booting from both kernel versions the same things happen: I can log in but hangs before showing the desktop, but if I log to console I can run nvidia-smi properly, giving me information about the nvidia card working.

Comment: @quimere Edit your question and show me `dkms status`, `uname -r`, `ls -al /etc/boot`, `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`, and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema Question updated!

Comment: @quimere oops... small typo on my part... `ls -al /etc/boot` should have been `ls -al /boot`, but it's not that important. Ok, to eliminate a system or Nvidia driver problem, do this... either log into another existing user account, or, create another temporary user account called `test`. Then see if you can log into `test`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I created a new user, switched to nvidia with `sudo prime-select nvidia` and rebooted, trying to log into the new user but that didn't work either.

Comment: @quimere The problem is systemic. You indicate that both 5.0.0 and 5.1.3 kernels exhibit the same problem. Purge the Nvidia driver. Go to `Software & Updates`, `Additional Drivers` tab, and choose either nouveau, or the Nvidia driver (probably not 430) shown there. Retest. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I did what you told, but the issue persists =(

Comment: @quimere I had to go back and review the entire problem, and I now see what Marmayogi saw... the nvidia is blacklisted. Where did the nvidia-prime software come from, and why did it put /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf on your system? If nvidia-prime is not a part of the standard 418/430 nvidia driver install, and you installed it separately, we may need to uninstall it. Please give me more detail.

Comment: I tried installing Ubuntu 19.04 that comes with kernel 5.0.1 (I think) and the installation set me up the nvidia 418 and it's working properly. I tried the same setup on my 18.04 installation and it doesn't work =(

Comment: @heynnma Ubuntu installs nvidia-prime by default using the software & updates center, i always purged with a ```sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*``` and the prime package ended up reinstalling

Comment: @heynnema Since on a fresh install of ubuntu 19.04 the nvidia was working with nvidia-drivers-418, I tried upgrading my 18.04 installation to 19.04. By default, I had the 418 drivers and the kernel 5.0.0-16 but it wasn't working like in the fresh install, so I tried to install first the nvidia-drivers-430 and managed to build the drivers for the 5.1.9 using dkms, but even with that it's still freezing just after login. What I did try too is to boot into the 5.0.0-16 kernel and instead of freezing after login the screen flickers and returns me to the login prompt.

Comment: @quimere Sounds like you need to fresh install the original 18.04 with a fresh 19.04... but beyond that, I don't have any more suggestions for you. Sorry.